# Check whether an array contains a value from another array

Tags: arrays, perl, nested-loops

I have an array of objects, and an array of acceptable return values for a particular method. How do I reduce the array of objects to only those whose method in question returns a value in my array of acceptable values?

Right now, I have this:

```
my @allowed = grep {
    my $object = $_;
    my $returned = $object->method;
    grep {
        my $value = $_;
        $value eq $returned;
    } @acceptableValues;
} @objects;
```

The problem is that this is a compound loop, which I'd like to avoid. This program is meant to scale to arbitrary sizes, and I want to minimize the number of iterations that are run.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Put the return values in a hash.

Comment: What number of objects and acceptable values do you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could transform the accepted return values into a hash

```
my %values = map { $_ => 1 } @acceptedValues;
```

And  `grep` with  the  condition that  the key  exists  instead of  your
original grep:

```
my @allowed = grep $values{ $_->method }, @objects;
```

Anyway, `grep` is pretty  fast in itself, and this is just  an idea of a
common approach  to checking if  an element is in  an array. Try  not to
optimize what's not  needed, since it would only be  worth in really big
arrays. Then you  could for example sort the accepted  results array and
use a binary  search, or cache results if they  repeat. But again, don't
worry with this kind of optimisation unless you're dealing with hundreds
of thousands of items — or more.

Comment: (`exists` is not actually needed since every value in the hash is true)

Comment: @ikegami true, I removed it for simplicity. Still, using `exists` would be _slightly_ faster, right?

Comment: If it can't buy you time to brew a coffee, the speed optimization isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Elements supposed to be present in given arrays seems unique. So, I will make a hash containing the count of elements from both arrays. If there is any element with count greater than 1, it means its present in both the arrays.

```
my %values;
my @allowed;
map {$values{$_}++} (@acceptableValues, @objects);
for (keys %values) {
    push @allowed, $_ if $values{$_} > 1;
}
```